# Express JS routes optional parameter

Tags: node.js, express

I have a router like this

```
app.get('/users/:id',  (req, resp) => {
var id = req.params.id;
if (id) {
    Users.findById(id, (error, record) => {
        if (error) resp.send(error);
        resp.send(record);
        resp.end();
    });
} else {
    // return all users
    Users.find({}, (error, recordset) => {
        if (error) resp.send(error);
        resp.send(recordset);
        resp.end();
    });
}    
});
```

path `/users/164564` is working fine but path `/users` is not hit the route and returning error message like blow

> Cannot GET /users

I can create two routes like `app.get('/users',()=>{});` for path `/users` and  `app.get('/users/:id',()=>{});` for path `/users/164564`

Is it possible to maintain `id` as optional parameter? if no value for `id` param then return all records.

Comment: try `app.get('/users/:id?', ...)`

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ `app.get('/users/:id?',...)` works great! Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
app.get('/users/:id?',  (req, resp) => {...  // question mark was missing.
```

instead of

```
app.get('/users/:id',  (req, resp) => {...
```

this might help you out.. Thanks